# How to store a variable that don't change

Tags: python, list

I'm backtracking something for game like candycrush... And of course for my backtracking I need to change my initial board all the time...
But at the end of the game, it doesn't return the old_board.. How can I change that

I tried with a function:

```
def return_original_board(board):
    original_board = []
    for i in board:
        original_board.append(i)
    return original_board
```

And in my backtracking function I made a variable that stored this function, but I still change everything
and I can't use the copy() function

Comment: Is board a 2-dimensional array / nested list?

Comment: yes it is, and if you have also a way to that with random variable, you can say it

Comment: Check out **copy.deepcopy** in std lib.

Comment: Oh, never mind, you cant use it.

Answer (score 3):

Since board is a 2-dim `list`, `i` in your code is a `list`, too. Then, you will still be mutating those lists during the game. Change as follows:

```
for i in board:  # if board is a nested list, i is a list
    original_board.append(i[:])  # use a copy of the list
```

Or even shorter (using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and more telling variable name):

```
def return_original_board(board):
    return [row[:] for row in board]
```

Comment: can you explain also maybe how you would backtrack a game like candy crush to get the maximum score in the remaining moves

Comment: That seems out of the scope of this comment section (also I do not have nearly enough information to answer that). Why don't you post what you have tried in another question and ask for help there?